# What happens if I initialize an array to size 0?

Tags: c#, arrays

Let's say I have a function like:

```
void myFunc(List<AClass> theList)
{
   string[] stuff = new string[theList.Count];
}
```

and I pass in an empty list.

Will stuff be a null pointer? Or will it be a pointer to some random place in memory that is uninitialized?

Comment: It's quite useful when you need an empty IEnumerable<T> (usually for testing)

Comment: `Enumerable.Empty<...>` is even better.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

It will create an empty array object. This is still a perfectly valid object - and one which takes up a non-zero amount of space in memory. It will still know its own type, and the count - it just won't have any elements.

Empty arrays are often useful to use as immutable empty collections: you can reuse them ad infinitum; arrays are inherently mutable but only in terms of their *elements*... and here we have no elements to change! As arrays aren't resizable, an empty array is as immutable as an object can be in .NET.

Note that it's often useful to have an empty array instead of a null reference: methods or properties returning collections should almost *always* return an empty collection rather than a null reference, as it provides consistency and uniformity - rather than making *every* caller check for nullity. If you want to avoid allocating more than once, you can use:

```
public static class Arrays<T>
{
    private static readonly T[] empty = new T[0];

    public static readonly T[] Empty { get { return empty; } }
}
```

Then you can just use:

```
return Arrays<string>.Empty;
```

(or whatever) when you need to use a reference to an empty array of a particular type.

Comment: The key point I was confused about was whether an empty array takes a non-zero amount of space, as you call it.

Comment: As the information about its 'emptyness' has to be stored somewhere (i.e. the count) it has to take up some space. Given what I wrote in my answer, you could of course (but this is dangerous) have the internal guidline that instead of initializing arrays of length 0 you set the reference to null. But this may need some additional checks when such arrays are used and not be worth the slim space savings.

Comment: I still don't understand the reason you would ever want something like `new int[0];`.  I don't see how it serves any useful purpose since its immutable.

Comment: @NETscape: well what would you do if you were implementing a method returning an `int[]` and you didn't have any elements to return?

Comment: Which is what we just talked about in the C# chat room.  Why not return null? Returning an empty array will still consume memory due to the overhead needed, why not just eliminate empty arrays?  I could see one possibility being so you don't have to check if `null` then check `Length` when looping...

Comment: @NETscape: returning null is a pain for all callers. Returning an empty array gives a much more consistent, uniform experience. You can always stash a reference to an empty array to avoid allocating it each time you need to return one....

Comment: @JonSkeet That makes sense.  That's kind of what I was looking for in the answer.  You say they are useful in your answer, but don't really say why.  Then again the answer isn't asking why would you want to do that, so the answer is still a good answer.  Do you think you could add the details in your comment to your answer to prevent someone from asking "why are empty immutable  collections useful?"  I can then upvote :)

Comment: @NETscape: I can - but bear in mind that's not what the question was asking at all...

Comment: Visual Studio is complaining about my `new int[0]`, though. "*CA1825 - Avoid unnecessary zero-length array allocations. Use Array.Empty<int>() instead.*" (that was search for this message which brought on this Q&A)

Comment: @Pac0: If you can use `Array.Empty`, use that instead of any of the code from this answer. It didn't exist in 2010 though :)

Comment: "an empty array is totally immutable". Incorrect. It can still have a lock taken on it. Because of this corner case, passing around a shared empty array is potentially dangerous. One more reason in .NET locking should not be possible for every object, but only on a special designated class. Would free up object header space and save on some processing in the runtime.

Comment: @kaalus: It's as immutable as any object can be in .NET. I completely agree about locking on arbitrary objects, but I think it's throwing the baby out with the bathwater to stop using the word immutable just because of this corner case.

Comment: @kaalus: I've edited to "as immutable as any object can be in .NET" though.

Answer (score 12):

Why should it? It will just point to an array of size 0, which is perfectly valid.

I think the confusion here arises from the ambiguity of representing the absence of data either by an array of size 0 or a variable set to null (the same ambiguity exists for strings with an empty string or a string reference set to null). Both are valid ways to indicate such absence and it would arguably make more sense to have only one. Hence, on some databases (Oracle specifically) an empty string equals the NULL value and vices versa and some programming languages (I think, new versions of C# are one of them) allow to specify references to never be null, also eliminating said ambiguity.

Comment: "Both indicate the absence of data and there is no right or wrong way to indicate such absence." But conceptually, there usually is a difference between the two. It's like the difference between having an empty cardboard box and not having a box at all. (I hope I never have to work with databases where "" == NULL, as I would get quite confused by that.)

Comment: Oracle apparantly does. I also don't 100% agree with that, because of terinary logic (IS NULL vs = NULL).

Comment: NULL == "" is an evil Oracle "feature" - no sane system should generally treat them as equal. My opinion...^^

Comment: I think it is a matter of your viewpoint. If you come from a relational-algebra / logical point of view, where you insist on the features of terinary logic, of course such conversion is really bad. On the other hand, from a domain conceptual point of view there are two representation for the same concept of an non-exisiting string.

Comment: But even from a conceptual point one can make a difference between not having a string and having an empty string. A user might create a document associate with something so a change from null to an empty string occurs. As long as the user does not enter any text the string will remain empty but that is conceptually different from null.

Comment: Though there is no information added. What's the difference in conveied information between having no document at all and having an empty document? Of course you can assign some artificial meaning (e.g. that an empty document means the user intends to add content in the future - but thats a contract on a higher, semantic level), but I really think from a purely mathematical point of view, viewing a set of strings as an algebra, the empty string and a NULL string are the same.

Comment: In a database, NULL generally means "this value is unknown". So `MIDDLE_NAME IS NULL` indicates the middle name is unknown, while `MIDDLE_NAME = ''` means this person is known to have no middle name. In C#, the semantics of `null` are much wider (not applicable, not yet set, etc.), but empty strings and arrays would indicate—to me anyway—that the value has been determined to be empty. (Sometimes in a database NULL means "not applicable", but that irritates the hard-core RDBMS theorists. Use with caution.)

Comment: From a mathematical standpoint, it's the difference between the empty set and no set at all. The empty set is a perfectly legitimate set; it just doesn't contain anything.

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge In Oracle, `'' IS NULL` is TRUE. So be careful what you say about databases in general...

Comment: @ErikE - I didn't know that about Oracle. Strange! I guess I should have said, "In an ANSI-compliant database".

Comment: @JeffreyLWhitledge I haven't completely figured it out because of conflicting information, but I wonder if in Oracle `'' IS NULL` is only true for `varchar`, and `varchar2` properly treats `'' IS NOT NULL` as true.

Answer (score 5):

This is fine code.  You will get an Array object with zero items (allocations) in it.

Answer (score 3):

`stuff` will be a reference to an array with length `theList.Count` with all entries initialized to `default(string)`, which is `null`.

Comment: His point was that you pass an empty list to it, i.e. theList.Count is 0. This of course means that there won't be any entries initialized to anything.

Comment: In which case it will be a reference to an array with length 0 with all 0 entries initialized to null. ;)

Answer (score 2):

The following is in the C# language specification:

> - The computed values for the dimension lengths are validated as
>     follows. If one or more of the values
>     are less than zero, a
>     System.OverflowException is thrown and
>     no further steps are executed.
> - An array instance with the given dimension lengths is allocated. If
>     there is not enough memory available
>     to allocate the new instance, a
>     System.OutOfMemoryException is thrown
>     and no further steps are executed.

So for a length of zero, memory is allocated.

Answer (score 1):

If `theList` is an actual `List` object, and is merely empty, then `theList.Count` is going to return 0. Which means that the declaration becomes

```
string[] stuff = new string[0];
```

In other words, `stuff` will just be an array (of strings) with length 0.

Comment: No, stuff will be an empty array of strings, not an empty string.

Comment: I'm pretty sure stuff is an array of strings, not a string!?

Comment: @Eric: I know, I got `string` mixed up with `char` and was thinking in C/C++ terms (thinking too fast has always been one of my failures). Corrected my answer before I even saw your comment.

Answer (score 1):

Linq `.Concat` will throw an exception if any of the arguments is null(which can occur in my case). So I had to do something like this in my code:

```
public string[] ConcatUsers(string[] users1, string[] users2)
{
    return (users1 ?? new string[0]).Concat(users2 ?? new string[0]).ToArray();
}
```

(just an example where 0-size array initializer could be useful)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you ensure that your List<> that you actually pass in to the method was initialized somewhere, like

```
List<Stuff> myStuff = new List<Stuff>;
```

the list will not point to null. It will be a list of zero Stuffs.