# Static allocation appears on heap after invocation

Tags: c#, .net, memory, allocation

In a previous thread I posted, it was stated that invoking `Array.Empty<int>()` would return an object from a memory location which was statically allocated, either at runtime or during the first usage of the static Array class.

However, using Rider's memory feature, I find that even after invoking an unrelated method in the Array class, invoking `Array.Empty<int>()` makes a new int array with size zero appear on the heap.

Should the object I am seeing appear on the heap already have been there (i.e., in the Before image)? I'm a bit confused.

Before:

[image]

After:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When do static variables get initialized in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3965976/when-do-static-variables-get-initialized-in-c).  As the poster for your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72088530/array-emptyint-why-does-rider-show-an-allocation-occurred-but-benchmarkdot) said _"[Array.Empty points to an array that the framework has already **statically allocated**"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72088610/585968)_

Comment: @MickyD Thank you. From your second link, I was able to find [this](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/BeforeFieldInit), which was very useful in answering my question.